# Which WCF security scenario should I use?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

I'm new to WCF and am overwhelmed by the options available for securing my WCF service.  What is the security model best suited for this situation?

Server:
Must have access to the context of a particular publicly available ASP.Net application, running on IIS 6.  However, the the service should only be available to a single client on the Intranet.  Basically, the service needs to do operations on the public web site but the service itself should be entirely unavailable to the public.  I would like to avoid SSL usage for the service.

Client:
An ASP.Net intranet application running on an in-house server (different machine than the above application but also using IIS 6).  There will be just this single client to the service.

The code seems rather straighforward - I have my service contract in a shared library between the two ASP.Net applications.  I need lots of help in figuring out how to set up each web.config to provide some type security such that the public access to the "server" application cannot use the service at all, whereas the "client" web application has full trusted access to the service.

Comment: BTW, since there is just this single client to the WCF service, I have no need for user authentication or any type of authentication to differentiate between valid users.  If I can store credentials within code in a shared library between the client and server, or something to that effect, that would be simplest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of options and their combinations is indeed staggering - that's why both Microsoft and also renowned WCF guru Juval Lowy have come up with "security scenarios" which should help you focus on a few, manageable scenarios that might be of use.

See this blog post by [J.D. Meier](http://blogs.msdn.com/jmeier/archive/2008/04/04/patterns-and-practices-wcf-security-application-scenarios.aspx) for the Microsoft approach, and Juval's ideas are best summed up in David Sackstein's [blog post series](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2009/06/11/wcf-security-scenarios-read-out-loud.aspx).

For an in-house, behind-the-corporate firewall solution, you're best bet is probably the `netTcpBinding` with Transport-level security, and Windows credentials.

UPDATE: Unfortunately, netTcpBinding can only be used on IIS7/WAS (with Vista, Win Srv 2008), and is **not** supported on IIS6 :-(

For this scenario, you'll either need to use one of the HTTP bindings, or create the host for your NetTCP-based service yourself (console app, NT Service).

Marc

Update:

if you want to make sure only local users that are members of your Active Directory Domain can access your service, your best bet is to use Windows credentials as authentication mechanism. In that case, an external user who doesn't have a Windows account in your domain won't be able to use the service and will be rejected.

You could probably set up basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding with transport security, using Windows credentials, for your service. If you use transport security, you'll be using https:// addresses and SSL must be enabled on your network, but on the other hand, you don't need to identify the service with a certificate.

Your service config would look something like:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="securedBasicHttp">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint name="Default"
              address="MyService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="securedBasicHttp"
              contract="IMyService" /> 
   </service>
</services>
```

A good resource for lots more info and also how-to videos would be the Patterns & Practice [WCF Security Guidance](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex - excellent, if almost a bit overwhelming at times.

You might also want to check out this list of [How-To articles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949079.aspx):

Comment: I have configured my server and client to use the configurations found in Sackstein's blogs for the Intranet scenario (uses netTcpBinding).  My client gets an error: You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.  Can a netTcpBinding be used on a service hosted by IIS in an ASP.Net application (which is not what Sackstein's example does)?

Comment: Ah, sorry - no, NetTCP can only be hosted in IIS7 (Vista, Srv2008) or self-hosted in a NT Service / console app.

Comment: IIS6 unfortunately only supports HTTP binding :-( If you're okay with it, the best performance would be basicHttpBinding with absolutely no security; I'd normally recommend not doing this, but in an intranet, you might be OK with this option. wsHttpBinding is much "heavier" and carries a lot more baggage, so that's probably not your best bet.

Comment: If I use basicHttpBinding with no security, won't anybody and everybody be able to access the service's methods through the publicly available website?  In my situation as described, the service is hosted in a public ASP.Net web application, even though I only want intranet users to be able to access the service.

Comment: Is there an example of how to set up wsHttpBinding somewhere without using a certificate?

Comment: I could never get a solution properly working with WCF.  Instead, it suited my purposes to go an entirely different route by just making a web form with no UI that did all the things my service could.  I just limited the accessibility of the web form to intranet users.